# Generate 9 digit unique value from a String

Tags: java, algorithm, unique, uniqueidentifier

I have employee data, each employee has address information. I need to generate a unique 9 digit (numeric or alpha numeric) value for postal code (5 chars) and address line1 (35 chars), which is a unique value to represent a location. It is also called as "Wrap number".

As shown in below picture, when address of two employees is same, then Wrap Number should be same, otherwise new value should be assigned.

Which algorithm is best suitable to generate 9 digit unique value?

P.S. I need to program it in Java.

[image]

Comment: How about a hash?

Comment: What happens when there's the same address, but a different post-code? Also, it seems like there might be some extra business-logic which you should get some clarification on. As such you could get by with the id assigned by the database you're using to store the record, with an optional left-padding of '0'

Comment: @HoriaComan if the postal code is different but address is same, then need to generate different value.

Comment: @Lissy, I looked into this hashcode option, for some strings 10 digit integer value is generated, for some strings 9 digit integer value is generated.

Comment: Hint: you're not going to be able to *guarantee* it's unique, simply because there are more feasible addresses than unique codes with 9 characters.

Comment: Create a database table with the primary key consisting of the name and address together.  Then let the database do the work of maintaining an auto increment column.  Other than this, some sort of UUID trick in Java may be the best you can do.

Comment: append row number (or index column value) at star or end to UniqueCode column value

Comment: What's the real purpose of this?  How are you accessing/indexing this data?

Comment: Is this a home work assignment, or something that is going to be used in a real commercial environment? If it's homework, I wonder if you are missing some subtle aspect of the requirements. If it's a real business requirement, what are the wrap codes going to be used for? Maybe they aren't supposed to be unique, but are meant to group nearby addresses into a route for delivery, etc.

Comment: @erickson its not an assignment, it is our business requirement. as you mentioned above, if group of employees are sharing same shipping address, then we need to generate a unique value (Wrap number) for that address. This wrap number is used for tracking when confidential docs are shipped. (P.S. I am unable to provide too many details on this one because of confidentiality of our business purpose.)

Comment: @NaveenChappa Then no hashing scheme will work. In theory, it might be possible to come up with a specialized compression scheme that could work, but it would be much easier to use a database to allocate a sequence number. The identifier space is so small that you can't assume that you won't have collisions if you choose IDs randomly, so if you need random-looking wrap codes, you can use that sequence number as input to an encryption function to generate the actual wrap code.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is impossible. No, really, impossible.

You have a 5-digit ZIP code, which can be encoded in 17 bits. Then you have 35 characters of text. Let's say you limit it to upper and lower case letters, plus digits and special characters. Figure 96 possible characters, or approximately 6.5 bits each. So:

```
35 * 6.5 = 227.5 ~ 228 bits
```

So you have up to 245 bits of information and you want to create a "unique" 9-character code. Your 9-character code only occupies 72 bits. You can't pack 228 bits of information into 72 bits without duplication. See [Pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

A better solution would be to assign a sequential number to each employee. If you want to make those 9-character codes, then use a technique to obfuscate the numbers and encode them using base-36 (numbers and upper-case letters) or something similar. I explain how to do that in my blog post, [How to generate unique "random-looking" keys](http://blog.mischel.com/2017/06/20/how-to-generate-random-looking-keys/).

Comment: Addresses have very low entropy, which your analysis doesn't consider. With over 100 trillion unique codes available, and only a few billion addresses in the world to assign, the pigeonhole principle doesn't apply. Real compression, which can exploit the low entropy of addresses, might be a solution.

Comment: @erickson: True. Addresses aren't exactly random. Still, reducing the problem space doesn't eliminate the possibility of hash collisions, just reduces it somewhat. Using a 64-bit hash, for example, the probability of a collision reaches 50% with the generation of 2^32 codes (approximately). It's nearly a certainty with 2^34 codes. So even with "only" a few billion addresses in the world, it's highly likely that duplicates will be generated. And we still have the problem of encoding those values into a 9-character identifier.

Answer (score 1):

The simple idea is to use the well-known hash algorithms, which are already implemented in Java.

```
private static long generateIdentifier(final String adrLine, final String postCode) {
    final String resultInput = adrLine + postCode;

    //do not forget about charset you want to work with
    final byte[] inputBytes = resultInput.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
    byte[] outputBytes = null;

    try {
        //feel free to choose the encoding base like MD5, SHA-1, SHA-256
        final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        outputBytes = digest.digest(inputBytes);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        //do whatever you want, better throw some exception with error message
    }

    long digitResult = -1;
    if (outputBytes != null) {
        digitResult = Long.parseLong(convertByteArrayToHexString(outputBytes).substring(0, 7), 16);
    }

    return digitResult;
}

//this method also may be useful for you if you decide to use the full result
// or you need the appropriate hex representation
private static String convertByteArrayToHexString(byte[] arrayBytes) {
    final StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte arrByte: arrayBytes) {
        stringBuffer.append(Integer.toString((arrByte & 0xff) + 0x100, 16)
                .substring(1));
    }
    return stringBuffer.toString();
}
```

I suggest you not to use MD5 and SHA1 because of the collisions which those hash functions can provide.

Comment: How do you guarantee that result is of length=9?

Comment: This can't possibly work. He has on the order of 300 bits of information and you're generating a 64-bit hash. By the Pigeonhole principle, we know that multiple keys will hash to the same value. Your algorithm has collision problems, too. Furthermore, a 64-bit binary value converted to hexadecimal will give you a 16-byte string. The OP asked for 9 characters. Even if you used base-64 to encode it, the string would be 12 characters.

Comment: Okay, so I was mistaken: it's about 228 bits of information. That's still significantly larger than your 64 bits.

Comment: MD5 can only produce collisions when someone deliberately alters a message. SHA-1 collisions, again, don't just happen, they are made with deliberate intent, and even more processing time.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be this:

```
String str = addressLine + postalCode;
UUID uid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(str.getBytes());
return makeItNineDigits(uid);
```

Where `makeItNineDigits` is some reduction of the UUID string representation to your liking. :)
This could be `uid.ToString().substring(0, 9)`. Or you could take the two long values `getLeastSignificantBits`, `getMostSignificantBits` and create a 9-digit value from them.

Comment: It would result in collision

Comment: Could you be more specific? @vish4071

Comment: Default UUID is not of 9 chars. So, if you take the substring to 9 chars, it would result in collision

Comment: Cutting off the first 9 chars isn't the best solution. But it's obvious that 9 digits will never suffice to avoid a clash for all possible addresses. The name space is just too big. What's more important is that the UUID generates a well-balanced random distribution from the input array. OP may takes this output to reduce it to the desired 9-digit space. Anyway, thx for pointing this out. @vish4071

Comment: UUID is a 128-bit structure. The OP has about 228 bits to encode. You simply cannot guarantee uniqueness even if you used the entire UUID.

Answer (score 0):

A simple option might be to just take advantage of the hashing built in to Java....

```
String generateIdentifier(String postCode, String addressLine) {
  long hash = ((postCode.hashCode() & 0xffffffffL) << 14L) 
          ^ (addressLine.hashCode() & 0xffffffffL); 
  return Long.toString(hash, 36);
}
```

Comment: @Stefan Haustein, with this solution, generated result is 15 digit length. if trim it to 9 digits per my requirement, I may end up with duplication

Comment: I have adjusted the shift to actually generate 9 digits only and tested the code. It shouldn't have produced more than 10 or 11 before. Typo?

Comment: @NaveenChappa: a 9-character alphanumeric (upper case letters, and numbers) code can represent approximately 10^14 unique items. The problem isn't the representational length, but rather than there is a chance of generating duplicate hash codes for non-equal strings.